# Trim last chars from a line

Tags: shell-script, string, csv

I have a `csv` file and the lines have different length. But all of them ends with a number surrounded by a pair of braces. For example,

```
........{5}
........{16}
```

I'd like to remove the number and the braces or maybe replace them for double quotes, for example. The result could be

```
........
........
```

or

```
........"
........"
```

I only found solution for lines with fixed length or with the same string at the end of line.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/{[0-9]\+}$//' file.csv
```

The standard equivalent:

```
sed 's/{[0-9]\{1,\}}$//' file.csv
```

Or:

```
sed 's/{[0-9][0-9]*}$//' file.csv
```

Replace `//` with `/"/` if you want to replace with `"` instead of deleting.

Comment: Nice! How to do this and save the result on the same file. Maybe `sed -e`?

Comment: `sed -i` to save in-place

Comment: OSX BSD sed won't support `\+`. That's why stephae edited your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this GNU sed command to replace last `{..}` with doublequotes,

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)\{.*\}$/\1"/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
........{5}
........{16}
avhjjk{23}

$ sed -r 's/^(.*)\{.*\}$/\1"/g' file
........"
........"
avhjjk"
```

And through `awk`,

```
$ awk '{gsub (/{.*}$/,"\""); print}' file
........"
........"
avhjjk"
```

Comment: to save change made through `sed`, `sed -ri .... file` and in awk, it would be `awk ... infile > outfile`

Comment: You can simplify that: `sed -r 's/\{.*\}$/"/g'` -- there's no need to capture the beginning of the line just to replace it with itself.